# Circular bitwise operation - as3

Tags: actionscript-3, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am new to the concept of Bitwise operations, and was messing around with some examples today. Everything seemed clear up until the point I tried to make a function to perform a circular bitshift on a `uint`:

```
    private function rotateLeft(value : uint, shift : int) : uint {
        if ((shift &= 31) == 0)
            return value;
        return (value << shift) | (value >> (32 - shift));
    }
```

Any ideas why does this not work? This seems simple, but I think I am missing something obvious.

EDIT:

I was stupidly trying to shift a colour value (e.g. 0xFF0000) and expecting something along the lines of 0x0000FF, when in actual fact I was getting 0xFF000000 (which is correct, due to the length of a `uint`) - the most significant bytes are for the alpha value.

Comment: What values are you testing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - always keep your shift in the range => `shift &= 31`

2 - use an unsigned shift right (`>>>`), otherwise you will have the bit sign that will propagate into your number, so for example `(0x80000000 >> 16)` will be `0xffff8000` and not `0x00008000`.

```
function rotateLeft(value : uint, shift : int) : uint {
 shift &= 31;
 return (value << shift) | (value >>> (32 - shift));
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me find out what was wrong. Turns out that I was getting the correct result, but it was just not what I was expecting!